# Running a large sql file in Linux mysql in the background

Tags: linux, mysql

I have very large sql script (export of mysql tables) which I want to run for mysql/Linux probably in the background without any interruption and it should store logs as well. Also if there is any error it should proceed further without stopping in the middle.
How this can be done in a best way possible?
Editing the sql file is taking time as it's very large.

I am trying to move the data from one server to other.
DB structure is same so want to move data only not the other metadata.

Comment: Especially the last part sounds like a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Consider `screen` or `tmux`. There are lots of questions (and answers) about both here

Comment: In fact, most software that does what you want (read a large SQL export) explicitly uses transactions to make sure they *do* stop and abort safely in case of an error, because an inconsistent database is about as bad as it can get.

Comment: What is it you are asking? I don't see any question here. You are only telling us what you will do. OK, so what do you need from us?